# Как протестировать TRANSACTION READ UNCOMMITTED?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Привет . 
Изучаю данную тему но никак не могу протестировать данную возможность в SQLMAN.STUDIO .

Исходная таблица с одного поля

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [n] [int] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(....)
```

Запускаю первую транзакцию в отдельном окне

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION BeforeUpdate  --ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRY
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
      INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3);
      SELECT  *,'before second' FROM t1
       WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
       INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4);
       SELECT  *,'after second' FROM t1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --BeforeUpdate;
END CATCH
```

и вторую

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION BeforeUpdate  --ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN TRY
    SET  TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
      INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
       WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
       INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2);
       SELECT  *,' after fisrt' FROM t1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION --BeforeUpdate;
END CATCH
```

Хотелось получить доступ к грязному чтению в соотв. этой инструкции 
При запросе `SELECT  *,'after second' FROM t1` хотелось получить доступ к записи добавленой при  `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (2);` и `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);`  но не получаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш пример выбирает 1, 2, 3 в первом окне и 1, 3; 1, 2, 3, 4 на моей машине. И оставляет две висящих транзакции. Может вы просто с временем запуска не угадываете?

Попробуйте пример попроще

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (42);
```

Во втором окне прочитать данные с уровнем изоляции по умолчанию (READ COMMITTED):

```
SELECT * FROM t1
```

Во третьем окне указать уровень изоляции READ UNCOMMITTED и прочитать данные:

```
SET TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT * FROM t1
```

Во втором окне вы получите данные без 42. А в третьем - со вставкой 42.